# DllImport declaring and using methods from C++ in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have used DllImport in the past, but I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out the correct way to declare and use a particular method due to the parameter types. Here is the C++ prototype:

```
//  PTRobot_EnumRobots
//
//  Description:
//      Function to enumerate the Robots on the system.
//  Params:
//      phRobots    points to an array of HANDLEs to store
//                  the Robots found.
//      pdwNumRobots    points to a DWORD containing the number of HANDLEs
//                  in the phRobots array.  This value is an input
//                  and an output.  The user should specify the size
//                  (number of HANDLEs) of the phRobots array on input.
//                  The value of the pdwNumRobots on output will be the
//                  number of robots found.
//
//  Notes:
//      Both params will be updated upon successful completion of this
//      command.  phRobots will contain handles to robots connected to
//      this system. pdwNumRobots will will be updated with the number of 
//      robots found.
//      Also, note that the hDrives[] array in the PTRobotInfo will not be
//      valid until PTRobot_EnumDrives is called.
//
//  Return:
//      PTROBOT_OK if Successful
//      PTROBOT_INVALID_ROBOT if no robots found
//      PTROBOT_SEQUENCE if this command is called out of sequence
//      PTROBOT_INTERNAL if an internal error occurred
//      PTROBOT_OVERFLOW if the number of robots found is > the value in 
//                       pdwNumRobots
//
///////////////////////////
DWORD WINAPI PTRobot_EnumRobots(HANDLE * phRobots, DWORD * pdwNumRobots);
```

And here is the C++ usage:

```
HANDLE hRobots[10];
DWORD dwRet=0, dwRobots=10;

dwRet = PTRobot_EnumRobots(hRobots, &dwRobots);
```

Here is my attempt at declaring it in C#:

```
[DllImport("PTRobot.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern uint PTRobot_EnumRobots(ref IntPtr[] phRobots, ref uint pdwNumRobots);
```

usage:

```
IntPtr[] robotArray = new IntPtr[1];
UInt32 numRobots = 1;

status = PTRobotDLL.EnumRobots(ref robotArray, ref numRobots);
```

but I don't think that is right, because I keep getting "INVALID_ROBOT" returned, even though the method return "OK" in C++. I believe the issue is when it is trying to write back to those references, probably because I am not sure how to declare them.

Any insight into the proper way to declare the method in C#? especially with the odd HANDLE array reference?

Comment: Does this also happen with IntPtr[] robotArray = new IntPtr[10]; UInt32 numRobots = 10; which would more closely correspond to the C++ use?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, no change in the return from playing with the array size or the int value

Comment: First param should be IntPtr[] phRobots

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you saying it doesn't need the "ref" keyword?

Comment: Er, yes, precisely

Comment: An array is already a reference type, decays to a pointer to the object.  To the first element of the array, much like it does in C.  So you have to delete `ref`.  The only thing you have to worry about is to make the array large enough, that's why the PTROBOT_OVERFLOW error exists.